# Give readonly access to dashboard in superset

Tags: druid, apache-superset

I have a dashboard in superset, to which I want to give readonly access to some users and that user should also be able to view that dashboard in Dashboard tab.

I have created a Readonly user and have given him datasource access used in that dashboard and Gamma role. After logging into superset with the user I don't see any dashbaord in Dashboard tab, but I am able to open the dashboard using the direct url. And the Edit dashboard button is disabled over there.
If add this user to the owner of the dashboard, I can see the dashboard in the Dashboard tab, but opening it enables Edit button also which I don't want.

Is there a mid way to assign access to the user to see dashboard in list of dahsboard and able to open the same but not able to edit it?

Comment: How do we know what permission does what?
Is it mapped anywhere or hardcoded in any superset file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following permissions for the public role and assign the user to that role:

```
[can dashboard on Superset, can explorev2 on Superset, can explore json on Superset, can csrf token on Superset, can csv on Superset, datasource access on [DATASOURCE][DATABASE], can list on DashboardModelViewAsync, can list on DashboardModelView]
```

You just need to replace **datasource access on [DATASOURCE][DATABASE]** with your public datasource and database name

Comment: This does not seem to work on version 1.2

Comment: This does not seem to work on version 2.1 too